# red hat enterprise 6.3 repository for yum via internet

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I have installed a red hat enterprise 6.3 from scratch. The machine is surely connected to internet. When I do `yum repolist` I got `0`.

As far as I understood this happens because I didn't activated my licence.

Suppose that at the moment I don't have that activation code, which repository file I can insert manually in `yum.repos.d` folder to use `yum`.

If I am not wrong I might use CENTOS 6.4 ones; are the 2 equivalent and what issue I might experience by using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/440) it's stated that you can do it, just follow the recipe guide, changing versions accordingly.

From what I recall, CentOS is a rebuild from source of RHEL, and versions are paired. So if you're on RHEL6.3 your upstream mirror would be the CentOs-6-repos.

Comment: I agreed. At the end I sorted out and I subscriber to RH web side, activated the licence by calling rhn_activate and after that all online yum repository were available.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this, but whether you *should* or not is another matter.

Red Hat will not support packages from third-party sources, including the CentOS repositories.

If you're expecting this system to be supported by Red Hat, then don't add the CentOS repos and update from them, just register the system to RHN.

If you want to use CentOS repositories, then run CentOS.